# Change datetime to simple %m/%d/%Y in database with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, strftime

I have a field called :date that is a :datetime. I am trying to save that huge datetime string to a simple MM/DD/YYYY in the database, but am not having any luck. I have tried the 'american_date' gem, and have tried a separate call in the model here:

```
after_save :change_date

def change_date
    self.date.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
end
```

None of these have worked though. Any help? Thanks Stack!

Comment: Why do you want to change the storage format? Could you not use `date_format()` (in case of mysql) to display according to your liking?

Comment: First, you are not saving the object after you modified the date attribute. Second: you are setting (modifying) an attribute in an after_save callback, if you save it inside the change_date, then it will call the after_save again which will modify the variable, etc.: Endless loop! Then, @vinodadhikary is right, you should not "complain" about the format inside the DB since you can change it on the display to the format you want.

Comment: I'm new to Rails so I'm learning. What would be the correct way to go about updating the format then? The reason for changing the format is because it's being passed via XML and the receiving object needs it in that format. It's not about the display to the web app, but the format necessary for the receiving entity.

Comment: Well its really confusing what you want.Whats that datatype of your table column you are trying to save in and what you really want from that column? A date or a datetime?

Comment: I only want a date, but in the format of MM/DD/YYYY. I have a time column that I would try to apply the same procedure to as well.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

Add a file to config/initializers with the following code:

```
Date::DATE_FORMATS[:default]="%m/%d/%Y"
Time::DATE_FORMATS[:default]="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M"
Time::DATE_FORMATS[:db]="%m/%d/%Y"
```

and see the [railcast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/31-formatting-time?view=asciicast).